# He was bawling his eyes out. (his eyes are complement or object?)

Tags: parts-of-speech, adverbial-phrases, emphasis

> He was bawling his eyes out.

I think if someone says 'He was bawling', this makes sense.

But in which way, was he bawling? Making his eyes out?

If I am correct, I would like to regard 'his eyes out' as a complement.

But purely seemingly, 'bawl' is a verb and 'his eyes' are a noun.

In 'General Verb+Noun', Noun is treated as an object.

Comment: This is an informal expression. As a baby, my little sister was always _bawling her head off_, but it doesn't seem to have affected her too much.

Comment: "Crying his eyes out," is much more common: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=crying+*+eyes+out%2Cbawling+*+eyes+out&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: My sister also used to _sob her socks off_.

Comment: "Bawling" has two complements: the object "his eyes" and the prepositional complement "out". We know that "out" must be a complement because if its dropped the sentence becomes ungrammatical. Incidentally, objects are complements, but to avoid confusion we normally call them objects.

Answer (score 3):

There's an idiomatic tradition in English of adding *figurative* phrases like "his eyes out", "her ears off", "their lungs out" and so on after *intransitive action verbs*.

They all have the structure *[ possessive adjective + noun + particle ]*. The only particles I can think of that are used in this structure are "out" and "off", but there may be more.

They all act as adverbials of manner, modifying the action verb.

They have the function of emphasizing the extent of the action.

So, to "bawl your eyes out" means to bawl hard and for a long time, as if long and hard enough to make your eyes come out -- but not really. To "talk someone's ears off" means to talk a lot, as a chatterbox does at a party. To "scream your lungs out" means to scream loud and for a long time, as sports fans do at a championship game.

Comment: I bet you worked your ass off composing that.

Comment: Does this answer the question, though? What's the verdict on the grammatical relations?

Comment: It's more often done by someone or something *else*, but *I'm doing my head **in*** looks to me like a different preposition for the same basic construction.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - in the army, 'doing your legs' means 'ruining your career prospects' and if my sister was late home my father used to _do his nut_.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: But he never "did his nut **in**", I bet! That sounds like a bungled home vasectomy!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I see that as a different construction because "do" is a transitive verb that normally has a direct object, so there's nothing special about it grammatically. The examples in my answer are all intransitive verbs. Your example is similar to "burn the house down", or any other transitive phrasal verb

Comment: Not exactly. You can *optionally* append "down" to "burn the house" as a kind of intensifier. But there's no such choice with "do someone's head" - without the final preposition, the sequence is meaningless.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's why I lean towards calling "do ... in" a phrasal verb.

Answer (score 2):

> *He was bawling his eyes out.*

It's somewhat idiomatic but it can still be analysed.

Bawling" has two complements: the object "his eyes" and the prepositional complement "out".

We know that "out" must be a complement because if it is dropped the sentence becomes ungrammatical. Obligatory items are always complements.

Comment: If the 'bawl' is instransitive, there is no object.

Comment: @gomadeng In my analysis, "bawl" is transitive.